# How to set order of the nodes in Sankey Diagram Plotly

Tags: python, database, math, plotly, sankey-diagram

So i am traying to make a cycle that gives different `sankey` diagram the thing is due to the `plotly` optimization the node are in different positions. I will like to set the standard order to be [Formal, Informal, Unemployed, Inactive]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=",")

Lista_Paises = df["code"].unique().tolist()

Lista_DF = []

for x in Lista_Paises:
    DF_x = df[df["code"] == x]
    Lista_DF.append(DF_x)


def grafico(df):
    df = df.astype({"Source": "category", "Value": "float", "Target": "category"})

    def category(i):
        if i == "Formal":
            return 0
        if i == "Informal":
            return 1
        if i == "Unemployed":
            return 2
        if i == "Inactive":
            return 3

    def color(i):
        if i == "Formal":
            return "#9FB5D5"
        if i == "Informal":
            return "#E3EEF9"
        if i == "Unemployed":
            return "#E298AE"
        if i == "Inactive":
            return "#FCEFBC"

    df['Source_cat'] = df["Source"].apply(category).astype("int")
    df['Target_cat'] = df["Target"].apply(category).astype("int")

    #    df['Source_cat'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df.Source)
    #    df['Target_cat'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df.Target)
    df["Color"] = df["Source"].apply(color).astype("str")
    df = df.sort_values(by=["Source_cat", "Target_cat"])
    Lista_Para_Sumar = df["Source_cat"].nunique()
    Lista_Para_Tags = df["Source"].unique().tolist()
    Suma = Lista_Para_Sumar
    df["out"] = df["Target_cat"] + Suma
    TAGS = Lista_Para_Tags + Lista_Para_Tags
    Origen = df['Source_cat'].tolist()
    Destino = df["out"].tolist()
    Valor = df["Value"].tolist()
    Color = df["Color"].tolist()

    return (TAGS, Origen, Destino, Valor, Color)


def Sankey(TAGS: object, Origen: object, Destino: object, Valor: object, Color: object, titulo: str) -> object:
    label = TAGS
    source = Origen
    target = Destino
    value = Valor
    link = dict(source=source, target=target, value=value,
                color=Color)
    node = dict(x=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], y=[1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0], label=label, pad=35,
                thickness=10,
                color=["#305CA3", "#C1DAF1", "#C9304E", "#F7DC70", "#305CA3", "#C1DAF1", "#C9304E", "#F7DC70"])
    data = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node, arrangement='snap')
    fig = go.Figure(data)
    fig.update_layout(title_text=titulo + "-" + "Mujeres", font_size=10, )
    plt.plot(alpha=0.01)
    titulo_guardar = (str(titulo) + ".png")
    fig.write_image("/Users/agudelo/Desktop/GRAFICOS PNUD/Graficas/MUJERES/" + titulo_guardar, engine="kaleido")


for y in Lista_DF:
    TAGS, Origen, Destino, Valor, Color = grafico(y)
    titulo = str(y["code"].unique())
    titulo = titulo.replace("[", "")
    titulo = titulo.replace("]", "")
    titulo = titulo.replace("'", "")
    Sankey(TAGS, Origen, Destino, Valor, Color, titulo)
```

The expected result should be.
The expected result due to the correct order:

[image: The expected result due to the correct order]

The real result i am getting is:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem earlier. I hope this will work for you. As I did not have your data, I created some dummy data. Sorry about the looooong explanation. Here are the steps that should help you reach your goal...
This is what I did:

1. Order the data and sort it - used `pd.Categorical` to set the order and then `df.sort` to sort the data so that the input is sorted by `source` and then `destination`.
2. For the sankey `node`, you need to set the `x` and `y` positions. x=0, y=0 starts at top left. This is important as you are telling plotly the order you want the nodes. One weird thing is that it sometimes errors if `x` or `y` is at 0 or 1. Keep it very close, but not the same number... wish I knew why
3. For the other x and y entries, I used ratios as my total adds up to 285. For eg. Source-Informal starts at x = 0.001 and y = 75/285 as Source-Formal = 75 and this will start right after that
4. Based on step 1, the `link` -> `source` and `destination` should also be sorted. But, pls do check.

Note: I didn't color the links, but think you already have achieved that...
Hope this helps resolve your issue...

**My data - sankey.csv**

```
source,destination,value
Formal,Formal,20
Formal,Informal, 10
Formal,Unemployed,30
Formal,Inactive,15
Informal,Formal,20
Informal,Informal,15
Informal,Unemployed,25
Informal,Inactive,25
Unemployed,Formal,5
Unemployed,Informal,10
Unemployed,Unemployed,10
Unemployed,Inactive,5
Inactive,Formal,30
Inactive,Informal,20
Inactive,Unemployed,20
Inactive,Inactive,25
```

**The code**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sankey.csv') #Read above CSV

#Sort by Source and then Destination
df['source'] = pd.Categorical(df['source'], ['Formal','Informal', 'Unemployed', 'Inactive'])
df['destination'] = pd.Categorical(df['destination'], ['Formal','Informal', 'Unemployed', 'Inactive'])
df.sort_values(['source', 'destination'], inplace = True)
df.reset_index(drop=True)

mynode = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ['Formal', 'Informal', 'Unemployed', 'Inactive', 'Formal', 'Informal', 'Unemployed', 'Inactive'],
      x = [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999],
      y = [0.001, 75/285, 160/285, 190/285, 0.001, 75/285, 130/285, 215/285], 
      color = ["#305CA3", "#C1DAF1", "#C9304E", "#F7DC70", "#305CA3", "#C1DAF1", "#C9304E", "#F7DC70"])

mylink = dict(
    source = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3 ], 
    target = [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
    value = df.value.to_list())

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    arrangement='snap',
    node = mynode,
    link = mylink
)])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=20)
fig.show()
```

**The output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! For me, setting the x-values in the OPEN interval (0.0, 1.0), so not to 0.0 and `arrangement='snap'` did the trick!