# Is there a way to save the manually edited interactive plots from plotly in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, sankey-diagram

I am plotting a sankey diagram using plotly in jupyter notebook. The resulted plot is as follows:
[image]

while I need everytime to manually edit it to produce the following plot:
[image]

The problem is that I could not find any function or way to save the edited plot. when I use  fig.write_image(), the original figure is saved, not the one edited by me.

the code I use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go


nodes_headers = nodes.pop(0)
links_headers = links.pop(0)
df_nodes = pd.DataFrame(nodes, columns = nodes_headers)
df_links = pd.DataFrame(links, columns = links_headers)

# Sankey plot setup
data_trace = go.Sankey(
    arrangement = "snap",
    orientation = "h",
    valueformat = ".0f",
    node = dict(
      pad = 10,
     thickness = 30,
      line = dict(
        color = "black",
        width = 0.5
      ),
      label =  df_nodes['Label'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      color = df_nodes['Color']
    ),
    link = dict(
      arrowlen = 40,  
      source = df_links['Source'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      target = df_links['Target'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      value = df_links['Value'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      color = df_links['Link Color'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      #label = df_links['Label'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      #hoverinfo="all",  
      #hovertemplate='Source: %{source.label}<br>Target: %{target.label}<br>Value: %{value}',
        
  )
)

layout = dict(
        title = "SENEK_Energiefluss_Diagramm",
    height = 750,
    width = 1000,
    font = dict(
      size = 10),)

fig = go.Figure(data=[data_trace], layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping you using the screen capture you posted? I'm struggling to think of a use case that has you edit the graph manually but save the image automatically outside of maybe resolution loss. Otherwise, this explanation for changing the order of the targets of a Sankey diagram might be helpful so that you can have an output that looks closer to your edited one by default https://stackoverflow.com/a/72764554/11825005

Comment: @Rufus yes it is the resolution issue. Specifying coordinates of each node makes making a plot using powepoint more time efficient if I have 500 energy stations to model as in my case.

Comment: Not following how you are editing it 'manually' here. And with little details it is hard to tell if maybe you are just writing the wrong object. I did come across [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/allowing-users-to-edit-graph-properties-without-code-changes/72031) saying somethings without code changes and that there was a way to save the edits made that way to be persisting. But that involves Dash and since you shared little here, I cannot tell. I also came across this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070800/8508004) that says you can use a different overarching place to edit in.

Comment: @Wayne The generated plot is interactive, which means that I can push some nodes up or down to new positions as it is clear in the 2 figures i posted.  for my code, please find it above in my edited question.

Comment: It wasn't clear how you were doing the changes in the two images because you didn't describe it as you have now. Also your code is not useful as it is not self-contained. See under 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular about a minimal reproducible example. You can use toy data or even an example from the documentation that parallels your efforts but the code you now have added, while improving your post, isn't quite addressing things. There's many ways to share code & data these days, e.g., Github gists.